# 2 queries in 1 report group both by date Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 queries and will just list the fields they end up with (as opposed to links, as there are 6 tables linked in the first one)

1) qryEmployee_Order

```
Employee_ID
Operation_Date
"Employee Name"
"Order Name"
"Model Name"
"Operation Name"
"Wage Rate"
"Quantity Produced"
```

2) qryEmployee_Work

```
Employee_ID
Work_Date
"Employee Name"
"Work Name"
"Wage Rate"
"Hours Worked"
```

Basically there are 3 types of employees in the business I work for. I don't know the proper English terms for these, so I will just explain them.:

1. The ones paid by the amount they produce
2. The ones paid by the hours they work for
3. Mix of 1) and 2)

First query (qryEmployee_Order) is the first category, they are paid by the amount they produce (irrelevant of hours it takes). Second query (qryEmployee_Work) is for the second type of employees (hourly wage based).

My current report shows a monthly report for the qryEmployee_Order where Employee_Id is the filter to get the correct employee and then Operation_Date is the header in the report itself under which everything else is grouped (ie. everything produced by the employee on a given date).

I would like to also add under the Operation_Date the information from qryEmployee_Work in case he did some hourly work too.

I cannot get this to work, because my recordset is set to qryEmployee_Order only. I know subreport is probably what I'm looking for, but when I tried that, I couldn't get it to filter by date properly (ie. it would show all records of qryEmployee_Work on a given date in ALL records under the same date in qryEmployee_Order).

For example if there are 3 records under 01/06 in qryEmployee_Order and 2 records under 01/06 in qryEmployee_Work it would show a the 2 records for every record in qryEmployee_Order.

Ie.

```
qryEmployee_Order row1
qryEmployee_Work ROW1
qryEmployee_Work ROW2

qryEmployee_Order row2
qryEmployee_Work ROW1
qryEmployee_Work ROW2

qryEmployee_Order row3
qryEmployee_Work ROW1
qryEmployee_Work ROW2
```

What I want to get is:

```
qryEmployee_Order row1
qryEmployee_Order row2
qryEmployee_Order row3
qryEmployee_Work ROW1
qryEmployee_Work ROW2
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be get a list of the common columns that you wish to show and then use a union statement to assemble all the columns together as below:
Where there is no value use the Nz function to replace the null value with a zero value or a "-" to show that there is no value there

```
Select 
Employee_ID,
Operation_Date,
"Employee Name",
"Order Name",
"Model Name",
"Operation Name",
"Wage Rate",
"Quantity Produced",
WorkName,
WageRate,
HoursWorked

From (
Select 
Employee_ID,
Operation_Date,
"Employee Name",
"Order Name",
"Model Name",
"Operation Name",
"Wage Rate",
"Quantity Produced",
Nz([Work Name],"-") as WorkName,
Nz([Wage Rate],0) as WageRate,
Nz([Hours Worked],0) as HoursWorked
From qryEmployee_Order

union all
Select 
Employee_ID,
Work_Date,
"Employee Name",
Nz([Order Name],"-") as OrderName,
Nz([Model Name],"-") as ModelName,
Nz([Operation Name],"-") as OperationName,
Nz([Wage Rate],0) as WageRate,
Nz([Quantity Produced],0) as QuantityProduced,
"Work Name"
"Wage Rate"
"Hours Worked"
From qryEmployee_Work 
) As CombinedEmployee_Order_Work
```